# How to setup an Eclipse project for create a multi-release jar file?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, jar, multi-release-jar

If I want build a multi-release jar file (MRJAR) then I need two source folder that compile with different java versions. How can I setup this in Eclipse?

I can configure the Gradle build script for such building but what is the best practice for Eclipse?

I expected/want that if I run the project with different Java versions that I can debug the right versions for the running Java version.

Comment: There is a 2 years old feature request: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=533401